# Create object using django POST method

Tags: python, django

I have a question regarding Djanog views

I have to Create a Task object using the string(the object)that I am getting from POST method. This string is equal to the name field in the Task object.
the POST request contains : task \ username.

the page is in this url: http://localhost:8000/tasks/

after adding the task the user should see something like this :
Task Created: '**Task_Name_Here**'

this was my code and i know its not correct:

```
def list_create_tasks(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    task_name = request.POST.get('task_name')
    task = Task.objects.create(name=task_name)
    return HttpResponse(f"Task Created: '{task}'")
```

thanks for helping.

Comment: what you mean with `its not correct`?

Comment: i mean i dont get the result i want. the code has problem it seems

Comment: It's always good to specify an elif `request.method=="GET"`, and return a response there too. Are you sure it's posting?

Comment: i did define that too. but the problem remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a first glance, I guess you would need something which redirects to the new `/tasks/taks_name_123/` page. For this, you can use `HttpResponseRedirect` (instead of `HttpResponse`), as described in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial04/

Comment: This doesn't matter too much for the example, but yes. Always return a redirect after submitting a form. Otherwise, users can reload the page after submitting the form, and that will submit the form again.

Comment: i tried but didnt work. no other url is defined or should be. the only url pattern thats defined is = path('tasks/', list_create_tasks).
the user should see for example - Task Created: 'Study for 2 hours' - after sending post request.

Comment: Then you would need to post the whole `list_create_tasks` method (the 'get' part) and probably your template as well

Comment: and how is that so?

Comment: Because there might be a chance that those are the places which need to be modified? :)

Comment: i should not edit other files. just view. its a quiz